# Update Multiple Documents in MongoDb c# -Update Arrays

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update a collection of documents in my collection, I don't just want to update a field on the entity but rather the whole entity> am currently doing the update one by one using UpdateAsync but this is very slow for multiple entities

```
public class Car 
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<string> Coulors {get;set;} // updated 
   public IEnumerable<Model> Models {get;set;} // updated
   public string Name {get;set;} // Not set 
}
public async void UpdateMany(IEnumerable<Car> cars)
{
    var filter = Builders<Car>.Filter.In(x => x.Id, cars.Select(x => x.Id));
    
    var update = Builders<Car>.Update.Set(x =< x.Colours , ??);
    //var update2 = Builders<Car>.Update.Set(x =< x.Models, ??);

    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

    return await DbSet.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want "replace" - https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_ReplaceOne.htm

Comment: thanks, but no i am specifically looking to do a bulk update for performance reasons

Comment: OK, so you have a bunch of documents, and you want to replace all of them with one new document?

E.g. car 1 is a red porsche 911, car 2 is a green honda civic, and car 3 is a blue toyota rav4 and you want to update the entire entity so all 3 cars are now silver chevy camaros? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by " I don't just want to update a field on the entity but rather the whole entity" - maybe post 2 sample docs before and after your changes?

Comment: Sorry i was not clear, i have a bunch of documets to replace in one go i was hoping to use UpdateMany....

Comment: Do you have an index on the filter? what exactly are you changing - if you're changing the whole document, then you will end up with a collection of the same document over and over.

Having sample docs before and after would help understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: im changing two collections on the object a color  string[]and a model which is an array of models then there are one or two other fields which i didnt update. yes there is an Id on each object

Comment: that in on each car object, and istead of updating the objects one by one i want to bulk update all the car objects

Comment: What does your index structure look like? from the mongo shell,  db.collection.getIndexes()